# What is the equivalent of the '.' CSS selector for any attribute?

Tags: html, css-selectors

I'd like to select things similarly to how classes are selected (but I would like to use other attributes). In the same way that `class='item-button item-button-selected'` can be selected with both `.item-button` and `.item-button-selected`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of an HTML class selector for any attribute is `[attribute~=value]`, matching one of a set of space-separated values:

```css
[data-foo~="a"] {
  color: red;
}

[data-foo~="a"][data-foo~="b"] {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p data-foo="a">a
<p data-foo="a b">a b
<p data-foo="b">b
```

In case you're worried about specificity (if this is a [non-CSS use case](https://blog.novalistic.com/archives/2018/01/using-css-selectors-for-non-css/#history), you don't need to worry), attribute selectors and class selectors are equally specific.